# How do I create a function that performs cd then ls in fish?

Tags: fish

I have posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: Make the question look like a question, add an own answer and accept it.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the suggestion. I shall do that.

Comment: Voting to close this question because its not a question.

Comment: It is a very minimal question.  It needs more appropriate body text.

Comment: @Numeron I posted this question because I wanted others in the future who are seeking the solution to find this. I, for one, had to come up with this solution after reading some docs and experimenting because I was not able to find anything online on how to do this. It would have been nice if I found something like this.

Comment: It's pretty terrible that this question was closed, because this is a great question and something I wanted to be able to do! Instead of finding a good answer on SO, I had to go elsewhere. Since I can no longer answer this question and only comment, I'll leave my solution here. Add this to your ~/.config/fish/config.fish file:
`function echo_dir --on-variable PWD; echo "you are here: $PWD"; ls -GF; end;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add this to your config.fish file:

```
function cs
   cd $argv
   ls -ahl
end
```

Comment: My muscle memory will not let me type anything but `cd`. Also, this solution won't work if you use the `autojump` or `z` utilities. But, you can tie a function to the change of the `$PWD` variable by using the `--on-variable PWD` suffix on a function like so: (config.fish) `function list_dir --on-variable PWD; ls -GF; end;`

Comment: addinga  comment regarding this comment solution *which is fantastic*. it perform and `ls` also if you press `tab` and the completition need to look in other folder (e.g.` vf activate <tab>` . any way to avoid that?